# Multiple AddHostedService dotnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

When I try to register more than one **AddHostedService** the method **StartAsync**  invokes only the first one.

```
services.AddHostedService<HostServiceBox>(); // StartAsync is called
services.AddHostedService<HostServiceWebSocket>(); // DO NOT WORK StartAsync not called
services.AddHostedService<HostServiceLogging>(); // DO NOT WORK StartAsync not called
```

Comment: I think you need to post more information here. Maybe your IHostedService implementation (e.g. HostServiceBox) does not return a `Task.CompletedTask`?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @KrumBagashev see my answer bellow

Comment: It looks like you can add a singleton instead of `AddHostedService`, like this: `services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, MyService>();` Source: https://forums.asp.net/t/2156818.aspx?How+to+run+2+services+in+one+time+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below a code who work
I get around the problem by creating a helper

@statup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            JwtBearerConfiguration(services);

            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowCredentials();
            }));

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1); ;


            services.AddSignalR();

            services.AddHostedService<HostServiceHelper>(); // <===== StartAsync is called

        }
```

@HostServiceHelper.cs

```
    public class HostServiceHelper : IHostedService
    {
        private static IHubContext<EngineHub> _hubContext;

        public HostServiceHelper(IHubContext<EngineHub> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Task.Run(() => ServiceWebSocket(), cancellationToken);

                Task.Run(() => ServiceBox(), cancellationToken);

                Task.Run(() => ServiceLogging(), cancellationToken);

            }, cancellationToken);
        }

        public void ServiceLogging()
        {
        // your own CODE
         }

        public void ServiceWebSocket()
        {
 // your own CODE
        }

        public void ServiceBox()
        {
            // your own CODE
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //Your logical
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is not the same as running multiple hosted services by framework. One obvious flaw: no one processes exceptions from those 3 services.

Answer (score 10):

OK, this is 2022 and .NET 6 is out. Now days it is not a problem to run multiple hosted services, as long as they are represented by different classes. Just like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                services.AddHostedService<Worker2>();
            }).Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Both workers will run.

But what if we need **multiple instances of the same service class** to run parallel? That seems to be still impossible.

See relevant discussion here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/38751

I ended up implementing my own utility function to start multiple tasks in parallel and collect all the exceptions properly. Here:

```
/// <summary>
/// Runs multiple cancelable tasks in parallel. If any of the tasks terminates, all others are cancelled. 
/// </summary>
public static class TaskBunchRunner
{
    public class BunchException : Exception
    {
        public AggregateException Agg { get; }

        public BunchException(AggregateException agg) : base("Task bunch failed", agg)
        {
            Agg = agg;
        }

        public override string Message => $"Task bunch failed: {Agg.Message}";
        public override string ToString() => $"BunchException -> {Agg.ToString()}";
    }
    
    public static async Task Bunch(this IEnumerable<Func<CancellationToken, Task>> taskFns, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        using CancellationTokenSource combinedTcs = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct);
        CancellationToken ct1 = combinedTcs.Token;

        Task[] tasks = taskFns.Select(taskFn => Task.Run(() => taskFn(ct1), ct1)).ToArray();
        
        // If any of the tasks terminated, it may be because of an error or a cancellation.
        // In both cases we cancel all of them. 
        await Task.WhenAny(tasks); // this await will never throw
        combinedTcs.Cancel();
        
        var allTask = Task.WhenAll(tasks); // this will collect exceptions in an AggregateException
        try
        {
            await allTask;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (allTask.Exception != null) throw new BunchException(allTask.Exception);
            throw; 
        }
        
        // Why not just await Task.WhenAll() and let it throw whatever it is?
        // Because await will unwrap the aggregated exception and rethrow just one of the inner exceptions,
        // losing the information about others. We want all the exceptions to be logged, that is why 
        // we get the aggregated exception from the task. We also throw it wrapped into a custom exception, so the 
        // outer await (in the caller's scope) does not unwrap it again. :facepalm:
    }
}
```

Now we create a single hosted service and make its `ExecuteAsync` method run several tasks as a bunch:

```
class MySingleService
{
    private readonly string _id;
    public MySingleService(string id){ _id = id;  }
    
    public async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        await Task.Delay(500, ct);
        Console.WriteLine($"Message from service {_id}");
        await Task.Delay(500, ct);
    }
}

class MyHostedService: BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        MySingleService[] individuals = new[]
        {
            new MySingleService("1"),
            new MySingleService("2"),
            new MySingleService("3"),
        };
        
        await individuals
            .Select<MySingleService, Func<CancellationToken, Task>>(s => s.RunAsync)
            .Bunch(stoppingToken);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>();
            }).Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Note 1: the `TaskBunchRunner` class was taken from a real project and proven to work, while the usage example is made up  and not tested.

Note 2: The `Bunch` method was designed for background services, which do not naturally complete, they keep running until cancelled or failed. So if one of the tasks in a bunch successfully completes, others will be cancelled (which is probably not what you would want). If you need support for completion, I suggest checking the result of `WhenAny`: if the race winner has run to completion, we need to remove it from the array and `WhenAny` again.

I know it is not exactly what the OP asked for. But may be useful for someone who ends up here having the same problem as I had.

Answer (score 2):

**.NET 8 Update**

Before .NET 8 all hosted services ran sequentially (Not Background services) and that's the reason it waits until the first one is done and tries to execute another one.

But in .NET 8 you can easily fix this issue by setting the `HostOptions`.

So the idea is running all `StartAsync` (and also `StopAsync`) methods **Concurrently**

```cs
using WorkerService;
 
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.Configure<HostOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ServicesStartConcurrently = true; //<--- new .NET 8 feature
            options.ServicesStopConcurrently = true; //<--- new .NET 8 feature
        });

        services.AddHostedService<HostServiceBox>();
        services.AddHostedService<HostServiceWebSocket>();
        services.AddHostedService<HostServiceLogging>();
    })
    .Build();
 
host. Run();
```

**Note:**

BackgroundServices are implementing IHostedService interface behind the scenes but dotnet run behave them differently with a custom implementation of IHostedService, You can check this video if you want to know about them deeply:
https://youtu.be/ebUc-FyE0-o?si=ownikRwEDKOg1ayu

Comment: I needed to update the nuget package `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` to 8.0 before I could see the new properties. My project was set to .NET 8 but was running the 7.0 package.

Comment: The statement "all hosted services ran sequentially" is misleading. You obviously can run multiple services in parallel. What you probably meant to say is "Start sequentially". Where by "finish starting" we mean the moment of time when `RunAsync` method returns the task (which is still not completed).

Comment: @C-F hosted service custom implementation is different from background service for dotnet runtime and it behaves differently with them, but agree I need to update the answer, also you can check my video about it:) https://youtu.be/ebUc-FyE0-o?si=ownikRwEDKOg1ayu

Answer (score 0):

A hosted service is usually a single task so I'd do it with a singleton.

```
// Hosted Services
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, HttpGetCurrencyPairRequestSyncingService>();
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, HttpPostCurrencyPairRequestSyncingService>();
```

And when in my class,

```
public class CurrencyPairCacheManagementService : BaseHostedService<CurrencyPairCacheManagementService>
        , ICurrencyPairCacheManagementService, IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private ICurrencyPairService _currencyPairService;
        private IConnectionMultiplexer _connectionMultiplexer;

        public CurrencyPairCacheManagementService(IConnectionMultiplexer connectionMultiplexer,
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(serviceProvider)
        {
            _currencyPairService = serviceProvider.GetService<CurrencyPairService>();
            _connectionMultiplexer = connectionMultiplexer;

            InitializeCache(serviceProvider);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Operation Procedure for CurrencyPair Cache Management.
        ///
        /// Updates every 5 seconds.
        ///
        /// Objectives:
        /// 1. Pull the latest currency pair dataset from cold storage (DB)
        /// 2. Cross reference checking (MemoryCache vs Cold Storage)
        /// 3. Update Currency pairs
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stoppingToken"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <exception cref="NotImplementedException"></exception>
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("CurrencyPairCacheManagementService is starting.");

            stoppingToken.Register(() => _logger.LogInformation("CurrencyPairCacheManagementService is stopping."));

            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var currencyPairs = _currencyPairService.GetAllActive();

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), stoppingToken);
            }

            _logger.LogWarning("CurrencyPairCacheManagementService background task is stopping.");
        }

        public void InitializeCache(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var currencyPairs = _currencyPairService.GetAllActive();

            // Load them individually to the cache.
            // This way, we won't have to update the entire collection if we were to remove, update or add one.
            foreach (var cPair in currencyPairs)
            {
                // Naming convention => PREFIX + CURRENCYPAIRID
                // Set the object into the cache

            }
        }

        public Task InproPair(CurrencyPair currencyPair)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

ExecuteAsync gets hit first, before carrying on with what you want it to do. You might also want to remove the generics declaration I have because my Base class runs with generics (If you don't run your hosted service base class with generics then I don't think you'll need to inherit IHostedService and IDisposable explicitly).